# Mapkit pin color not changing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I'm doing the following and always get green pins:

```
pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];
        [pin release];
```

pin is of type "NSObject ".  All pins come out as green.  Should I be doing it differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your pin class implements the [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and I believe to get a non-standard pin color, you'll have to implement the [viewForAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:viewForAnnotation:) method.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"redpin"];
    newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
    newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
    return newAnnotation;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This looks similar to tableview dequeueing.  Should I check for null on newAnnotion first and give back the instance if it already exist?

Comment: Yes, that's what the docs recommend though for my purposes I didn't bother.  Check the link for viewForAnnotation.  It mentions the dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier method.

Comment: You definitely should as you could have many same annotations. I also advise you to check the type of annotation that's provided, for example if tit's a MKUserLocation annotation so you can return nil.